# Getting ArcMap reference without launching application?

Tags: arcobjects

I need to get hold of ArcMap properties in order to change the data source of the layers within it.

I have developed a similar utility earlier utilizing ICommand, but I was curious if I could get a reference to ArcMap application outside of it and change the layer sources and display the new map.

I am using the following code but it instantly launches ArcMap and after that I have no hold on the application i.e. if I terminate my application, ArcMap is still running in background.

Is it possible to get a silent, invisible reference to ArcMap?

```
IApplication pApp;
IDocument pDoc;
IMxDocument pMxDoc;
string MXDPath = "C:\\NORMALTEMPLATE\\OLD_Normal.mxd";

pDoc = new MxDocumentClass(); //ArcMap launches here
pApp = pDoc.Parent;

pApp.OpenDocument(MXDPath);
MessageBox.Show("Doc opened");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CAN access a running instance of ArcMap (including starting and closing that instance), but the best thing in your scenario is to use the [MapDocument](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MapDocumentClass_Class/001200000s1n000000/) class. It is specifically designed for purposes of working with a map document without the need to start an ArcMap instance.

Comment: Right. Creating an instance of MxDocument creates an instance of MxApplication (ArcMap).

Comment: OK, the happiness was rather short lived :(  *MapDocument.MapCount* makes the application crash for a MXT which has data source missing...

Comment: @ujjwalesri: I tried that specific case and had no problems. Are you properly checking out the licence?

Comment: @Petr: I forgot to check out the license. Did that, program moved further..but failed again at the same point...any ideas? I am getting this error: " could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND))"

Comment: Could you please post a full code sample? (Perhaps create a new question.)

Comment: I would rather create a new question...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't look into this carefully, but the [arcpy mapping module](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/) seems promising assuming that you aren't adverse to working in Python.

Comment: This looks good, but I don't have any working experience with Python. I am currently developing in Dot Net. But Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: The mapping module is pretty sweet, all things considered. It's a great start to map layout manipulation in python. I can only hope ESRI continues to make more parts of the UI (and its various functions) available outside of arcobjects.