# Custom Application throws HRESULT if MXD/MXT has layers with data source missing?

Tags: arcobjects

This is in continuation to [Getting ArcMap reference without launching application?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/getting-arcmap-reference-without-launching-application).

The idea of the application is to map layers (pointing currently to an unreachable server; server may be down, non-operational or behind a firewall) of a MXD/MXT of a document to another data source.

While I was able to achieve it, I faced a different issue as I move forward.
These are the steps I followed:

- Checkout ArcEditor license
- If checkout successful above, try connecting to *SDE.DEFAULT*
- If connection to ArcSDE successful, parse map layers
- For every layer parsed, change its source
- Finally, save map and close

The issue is, as soon as I try to get the map count (data frames) in the document, the application throws a HRESULT error (see below), and I am unable to proceed.

**could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND))**

I searched the internet for this error and at some places they have talked about ArcGIS not being able to "access" a file. In this case I doubt if thats an issue...

I am attaching relevant portions of the code, showing the location of the error.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
public static bool LicenseCheckout()
    {
        try
        {
            int ESRILicenseCheckoutReturnCode;
            bool ReturnResult;

            //checkout ESRI license: ArcEditor
            pESRILicense = new AoInitializeClass();
            ESRILicenseCheckoutReturnCode = (int)pESRILicense.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcEditor);

            ReturnResult = false;

            switch (ESRILicenseCheckoutReturnCode)
            {
                case 10:
                    //esriLicenseAvailable
                    ReturnResult = true;
                    break;

                case 20:
                    //esriLicenseNotLicensed
                    MessageBox.Show("You are not licensed to use the product!", "License Checkout Failure");
                    ReturnResult = false;
                    break;

                case 30:
                    //esriLicenseUnavailable
                    MessageBox.Show("You are not licensed to use the product!", "License Checkout Failure");
                    ReturnResult = false;
                    break;

                case 40:
                    //esriLicenseFailure
                    MessageBox.Show("There has been a licensing Failure!", "License Checkout Failure");
                    ReturnResult = false;
                    break;

                case 50:
                    //esriLicenseAlreadyInitialized
                    MessageBox.Show("The Product license has already been initialized." +
                    "Initialization can only be performed once!", "License Checkout Failure");
                    ReturnResult = true;
                    break;

                case 60:
                    //esriLicenseNotInitialized
                    MessageBox.Show("License not Initialized!");
                    ReturnResult = false;
                    break;

                case 70:
                    //esriLicenseCheckedOut
                    ReturnResult = true;
                    break;

                case 80:
                    //esriLicenseCheckedIn
                    MessageBox.Show("License ChekedIn successfully!");
                    ReturnResult = true;
                    break;
            }

            return ReturnResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }  

public static bool ConnectToSDE(string User, string Password, string Server, string Instance)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SDEConnectionSuccessful(User, Password, Server, Instance))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }  

 private static bool SDEConnectionSuccessful(string User, string Password, string Server, string Instance)
    {
        try
        {
            pConnectionProperties = new PropertySetClass();

            pConnectionProperties.SetProperty(Constants.ARCSDE_PROPERTY_SERVER, Server);
            pConnectionProperties.SetProperty(Constants.ARCSDE_PROPERTY_INSTANCE, Instance);
            pConnectionProperties.SetProperty(Constants.ARCSDE_PROPERTY_USER, User);
            pConnectionProperties.SetProperty(Constants.ARCSDE_PROPERTY_PASSWORD, Password);
            pConnectionProperties.SetProperty(Constants.ARCSDE_PROPERTY_DATABASE, ""); //not required for Oracle connections
            pConnectionProperties.SetProperty(Constants.ARCSDE_PROPERTY_VERSION, Constants.ARCSDE_VERSION);

            pWSF = new SdeWorkspaceFactoryClass();
            pWS = pWSF.Open(pConnectionProperties, 0);

            if (pWS != null)
            {
                //connection successful
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //cleanup
            pConnectionProperties = null;
            pWS = null;
            pWSF = null;

            ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser.ReleaseCOMObject(pConnectionProperties);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser.ReleaseCOMObject(pWS);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser.ReleaseCOMObject(pWSF);

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //nothing to release as objects will be needed later
        }
    }

    public static void ParseMapLayers()
    {
        try
        {
            //get a reference to ArcMap
            pMapDoc.Open(MXDFilePath, null); 
            pMap = pMapDoc.get_Map(0); // <<<<<<---- error at this line <<

            //iterate through all the layers            
            pLayers = pMap.get_Layers(null, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeSource()
    {
        pLayers.Reset();

        pLayer = pLayers.Next();
        while (pLayer != null)
        {
            if (pLayer is IFeatureLayer)
            {
                ChangeLayerDataSource((IFeatureLayer)pLayer);
            }

            pLayer = pLayers.Next();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you open the mxd successfully with arcmap?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is not occurring in the call to pMapDoc.Open(), because that method will throw STG_E_FILENOTFOUND if the MXD path is invalid?

Comment: @Kirk: The MXD in question is currently pointing to client-side database instance, which to us developers is not accessible. I need to re-point the layers to our development database. If I try to open the MXD in ArcMap it takes a hell lot of a time (4-6 hours) before it opens it with all the layers showing data source missing (red exclamation).

Comment: @Adam: Yes it does not throw any exception at the Open() method, works fine till there. As soon as I try to access any property of the Mapdoc, I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you have a resource in a SDE instance the layer will reference a SDE file followed by the resource (e.g. C:\ArcGIS\Catalog\connection_file.sde\sde_server_name.sde_account.my_mosaic_dataset).  You might be able to get around all this if you place a .sde file in the location those layers are looking, and setting them up in Catalog to point to your development SDE instance.